# createElement and pseudo classes

Tags: javascript

The css

```
div.online:last-child {
    color:green;
}

div.offline:last-child {
    color:green;
}
```

JavaScipt

```
var x=navigator.onLine; 
var div = document.createElement("div"); 
if (x==false) {
    var divContent = document.createTextNode("sorry, you're offline"); 
    divContent.className="offline:last-child";
    div.appendChild(divContent);
    var k = document.body.appendChild(div);
} else {
    var divContent = document.createTextNode("you are online");
    divContent.className="online:last-child";
    div.appendChild(divContent);
    var k = document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

here I am using `.className` to change the style of last word using the `last-child` pseudo class (so only offline and online are styled). I'm guessing there is a problem with the naming of the class in my js code.
Before I took this approach I used `setAttribute`, but I had little idea how to go about using pseudo classes using that. What class name (and / or code) should I be using?

Comment: try removing your `:last-child` in your js code.

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding the concept of a pseudo-class.

Comment: pseudo selectors can't be specified, they are determined by the browser based upon the state of the element.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't assign a class to a text node, only to an element. Assign the online or offline class to the div, not its text content.

Second, you can't directly assign a pseudo-class like `:last-child`. Selectors with such a pseudo-class in CSS are used to target elements that are the last child of their parent in the DOM tree.